# How to create a IList Dep property in DataGridTextColumn custom control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties, listobject

I want to pass a list object to my Custom control of datagrid DataGridTextColumn.
for this I used this code

```
public class DataGridListBoxColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
public IList<Student> ListItems
{
get { return (IList<Student>)GetValue(_ListItems); }
set { SetValue(_ListItems, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty _ListItems = DependencyProperty.Register("ListItems", typeof(IList<Student>), typeof(DataGridListBoxColumn));  
}
```

I XAML

```
 <local:DataGridListBoxColumn   Binding="{Binding M_Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" ListItems="{Binding Path= stud, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"  Width="100"/>
```

OR

```
<local:DataGridListBoxColumn   Binding="{Binding M_Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" ListItems="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridTextColumn}, Path=stud}"  Width="100"/>
```

Both are not working, Is there any method to pass list to my Custom control
Thanks

Comment: Where is `stud`?

Comment: @Rekshino Sorry, but you're right. Seems that I don't understand how the XAML parser handles bindings... OP should still adhere to this naming convention. I'm sure that I've seen cases where Bindings didn't work due to wrongly named identifier fields.

Comment: @Clemens No problem! :) As I said it was my first guess and you are right, that convention is to name abc**Property**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `DataGrid` columns is, that **they are not present in the visual or logical tree**, therefore you can't use `RelativeSource`. The possibility, which also has restrictions, is to set `Source` for your Binding with `x:Reference`. Restriction is, that you can't set as source UIElement, which contains element with binding. So you can't set your main window or datagrid, which contains the column as binding's source otherwise you'll get cyclical dependency.
Now put next to your DataGrid a hidden control as access to the data, or use some existing:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="studAccess" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<DataGrid>
<local:DataGridListBoxColumn .../>
</DataGrid>
```

and bind you dependency property of columns via this control(implied is, that `DataContext` of `studAccess` has a `stud` property):

```
<local:DataGridListBoxColumn   Binding="{Binding M_Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" ListItems="{Binding DataContext.stud, Source={x:Reference studAccess}}"  Width="100"/>
```

Comment: I added one TextBlock and binded as you explained, but I get null in Listitem property.stud is a list object in Vm. I have edited my code like above. Thanks

Comment: protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, Object dataItem)
        {
            textBox = (TextBox)base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
            textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
            Binding b = new Binding();

            b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridListBoxColumn), 1);
            b.Path = new PropertyPath("ListItem");
            tx.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
            return textBox;
        }

Comment: I binded to a text block , I get null in listitems.

Comment: @babucr Do create a `TextBlock` not within a `DataGrid`. I have edited my answear for it is more clear for you.